# How do you push just a single Git branch (and no other branches)?

Tags: git, git-push

I am working on a local git repository. There are two branches, `master` and `feature_x`.

I want to push `feature_x` to the remote repo, but I do not want to push the changes on the `master` branch.

Will a `git push origin feature_x` from my `feature_x` branch (`feature_x` branch already exists on remote) work?

I do not want to test this on my box, because I cannot push to master right now.

Comment: Take a look here: [remote](http://git.or.cz/course/svn.html#remote) and here: [push a branch to github](http://github.com/guides/push-a-branch-to-github) Sounds like it would work.

Answer (score 419, accepted):

yes, just do the following

```
git checkout feature_x
git push origin feature_x
```

Comment: With modern git you should be able to simply "git push origin HEAD", or even "git push HEAD" to push only currently checked-out branch.

Comment: Is it necessary to checkout to feature_x ?

Comment: yes, because if you are on master it would try to push the local master branch to the remote feature_x branch.  to not have to checkout first you would have to do "git push origin feature_x:feature_x"

Comment: @cpjolicoeur I saw in other questions (e.g: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765421/how-to-push-a-new-local-branch-to-a-remote-git-repository-and-track-it-too) ) they are doing `git push -u origin <branch-name>`. However you did not mention it. Is it necessary ?

Comment: @miss_R the `-u` option on a `git-push` command will set the upstream reference for tracking the branch just pushed.  This will make things like `git-pull` on that branch in the future already know which branch to pull from without specifying it. It is not required as an option to push a single branch, but is widely used because a lot of people do want to make the local branch track the remote branch they are pushing.

Comment: aha I see. Thanks a lot. In my case git push without `-u` was enough. But it's good to know for people who are interested.

Comment: Does this mean `git push origin master` only pushes the master branch and not anything else you've been working on?

Comment: Correct, that command would push the local `master` branch to the repository named `origin`

Comment: this doesn't seem correct, still picking up more than one commit

Comment: @AlexanderMills This question was about pushing a single git *branch* not a single *commit*

Comment: I think the first time you should use the `-u` once to initiate tracking. Afterward, just use `git push ...`

Comment: `fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`

Comment: @DmitriyOgureckiy replace `origin` with whatever the name of your git remote is

Answer (score 89):

By default `git push` updates all the remote branches. But you can configure git to update only the current branch to its upstream.

```
git config push.default upstream
```

It means git will update only the current (checked out) branch when you do git push.

Other valid options are:

- `nothing` : Do not push anything (error out) unless **a refspec is explicitly given**. This is primarily meant for people who want to avoid mistakes by always being explicit.
- `matching` : Push all branches having the **same name** on both ends. (default option prior to Ver 1.7.11)
- `upstream`: Push the current branch to its upstream
  branch. This mode only makes sense if you are pushing to the same repository you would normally pull from (i.e. **central workflow**). **No need to have the same name** for local and remote branch.
- `tracking` : Deprecated, use `upstream` instead.
- `current` : Push the current branch to the remote branch of the **same name** on the receiving end. Works in both central and non-central workflows.
- `simple` :  [available since Ver 1.7.11] in centralized workflow, work like `upstream` with an added safety to refuse to push if the upstream branch’s name is different from the local one. When pushing to a remote that is different from the remote you normally pull from, work as `current`. This is the safest option and is suited for beginners. This mode has become the default in Git 2.0.

Comment: Thanks, `current` was what I was looking for, by default `git push` in the `foo` branch will push it to the `origin/foo` branch.

Comment: @Dorian thanks, I agree that `current` makes more sense as a default.

Comment: @Dorian, @Zoltán - I feel `simple` makes more sense as a default. I've updated the answer with 'when to use what'. Pls have a look.

Comment: Note: since git version 2 the default value has changed to `simple`.

Answer (score 11):

Minor update on top of [Karthik Bose's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10829461/456814) - you can configure git globally, to affect all of your workspaces to behave that way:

```
git config --global push.default upstream
```

Comment: upstream wasnt recognized as a valid setting for me, had to put 'current' instead

Answer (score 2):

Better answer will be

`git config push.default current`

`upstream` works, except that when you have no branch on `origin` then you will need to set the upstream branch. Changing it to `current` will automatically set the upstream branch and will push the branch immediately.

Answer (score 1):

To push your current branch no matter what config you have:

```
git push origin $(git branch --show-current)
```

Comment: small note: older versions of git don't have the --show-current flag. For example git 1.8 which comes with RHEL7 doesn't have it. It is admittedly an old version of git!

Answer (score -3):

So let's say you have a local branch foo, a remote called origin and a remote branch origin/master.

To push the contents of foo to origin/master, you first need to set its upstream:

```
git checkout foo
git branch -u origin/master
```

Then you can push to this branch using:

```
git push origin HEAD:master
```

In the last command you can add --force to replace the entire history of origin/master with that of foo.