# Automatically track remote branch with git

Tags: git

When I'm using a local branch `mybranch`, I'd like to be able to push to and pull from `origin mybranch` using just `git push` and `git pull`. As it is, I have to tediously write out `git push origin mybranch` and `git pull origin mybranch`. If I try to use just `git pull` for example, I get:

```
There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> mybranch
```

And if I enter `git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/mybranch mybranch`, then it works. But this is almost as tedious as the previous commands. Can I just have git do this as default behavior? I've seen similar questions asked and the answers tend to suggest that newer versions of git do this, but I'm using git version 2.1.3, which is fairly new, so it can't just be that.

Comment: Next time you push, use `git push -u origin mybranch`. From then on, when you're on `mybranch`, `git push` and `git pull` will be enough.

Comment: With Git 2.37 (Q3 2022), a [`git config --global push.autoSetupRemote`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72401899/6309) can help.

Comment: Don't use `--global` unless you know what you are doing. You can get hard to find bugs a year later when you have long forgotten that you once used `--global`.

Comment: or always use global, in that way you know all your repository behave the same

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's not github, it's your local git, that does all this.

If you are creating `mybranch` locally with `git checkout` *and* it already exists as `origin/mybranch` in your local repository, you can simply `git checkout mybranch` and your local git will see that `origin/mybranch` exists and create local `mybranch` with `origin/mybranch` as its upstream.

On the other hand, if `origin/mybranch` does not exist yet and you're creating `mybranch` locally with `git checkout -b` or similar, you can't really set it to track the upstream branch that does not exist yet (you can *configure* it to track that branch but you'll get an occasional complaint that the upstream version is not there).

In this particular case, on the *first* push (the one that will create the branch upstream), you can use:

```
git push -u origin mybranch
```

which tells your local git to push `mybranch` to `origin` *and*, once that's done, set up `origin/mybranch` as the tracking-branch for `mybranch`.

Note that this is the same as running `git branch --set-upstream-to`: you do it *once*, after which it's set locally and you don't have to do it again.  It's just more convenient since you can do it together with the `push` that creates the branch at `origin`.  But you still have to remember to do it (once; you'll get reminded when you run `git push` without `-u origin mybranch`).

Answer (score 601):

As of git 2.37.0, this is now possible with git configuration.

Run to update your configuration:

```bash
git config --global --add --bool push.autoSetupRemote true
```

Then `git push` will automatically setup the remote branch.

Note: The `--global` flag means this will apply to all git commands on your machine (regardless of which repo it is), you can omit the flag to make it specific to a single repo on your machine.

Documentation:

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pushautoSetupRemote

> push.autoSetupRemote
>
> If set to "true" assume --set-upstream on default push when no upstream tracking exists for the current branch; this option takes effect with push.default options simple, upstream, and current. It is useful if by default you want new branches to be pushed to the default remote (like the behavior of push.default=current) and you also want the upstream tracking to be set. Workflows most likely to benefit from this option are simple central workflows where all branches are expected to have the same name on the remote.

Comment: I find it dangerous to tell to use `--global` without telling the user that they change the configuration for **all** repositories on the machine.

Comment: I added an explanation about global.

Comment: Why the `--add` flag? Can this setting have multiple options? And `--bool` isn't needed in this case either.

Comment: `git version 2.39.1` on my mac does not seem to take above into effect; when i run 'git pull' it still asks me to set tracking information.

Comment: You have to set the config and have pushed that branch first (which sets up the remote).

Answer (score 60):

One possible solution is to modify your git push behavior to `current` (note that this will also have some other side affects). You can do that either by modifying your `~/.gitconfig` directly (as a file and this assumes you are on Linux) or by executing:

```
git config --global push.default current
```

Now when you `push`, git will automatically push your current branch to a remote branch with **the same name** even if you don't specify it explicitly. In addition if your current branch does not have a remote equivalent, a remote branch will be created and your current branch will be set to track it (same as `git push -u origin new_branch` but with a single `git push`). Also have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948354/default-behavior-of-git-push-without-a-branch-specified) where the git push behavior is described in detail.

Comment: And `git config --global pull.default current` for automatic pulling of branch with the same name as the current one from the origin.

Comment: @AlexanderRodin not working, still asking to set upstream with git `2.15.0`

Comment: @AlexanderRodin this configuration option is documented nowhere. Are you sure it exists?

Comment: Docs https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pushdefault

Comment: I have `push.default` set to `current`, but that doesn't set up remote tracking on the first push. `git config --global push.default upstream` will probably help.

Comment: @AlexanderRodin Can't find `pull.default` in `man git-config`. Are you sure?

Comment: @Ivaylo I love you <3 I've always been annoyed by first having to run `--set-upstream`, but now I don't have to ever again. I've been far too dependent on Git GUIs apparently...