Git - Accidentally git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/branch the main branch
I accidentally pushed a git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/branch the b1 branch to merged with the main branch, I know that it will be merged but I accidentally clicked the push in the Github Desktop then after that I checked the Github, the main branch that my team commits is gone and the current commit in there is the b1 branch commit. I cannot find the original main branch. The main branch has become the b1 branch or rather it overwrite the original main branch. Is there a way to revert it to get back the original main branch?

If you're a beginner with git, these may be the easiest things to do: Ask your coworkers to push a recent copy of their main branch. Get it from a backup. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29422101/automatically-track-remote-branch-with-git to prevent this from happening again.

When you ran git push, the last line of the output would have been something like

   abc1234..afe2345 main -> main


Therefore the main branch on remote was previously on abc1234 and became on afe2345.
With GitHub Desktop, you need to view the logs to view this information:

gitHub Desktop view Executed Command

Help > Show Logs



You can push that sha back as main with
git push -f origin abc1234:main


Very good, but the OP used GitHub Desktop, not Git at the command line, to push.

@matt True, but OP sounded panicked enough to give the CLI a try ;-)

Right, but my point is, where will the OP get "the last line of the output"?

@matt Added mention of ‘Show Logs’ to view output from Git in GitHub Desktop.

Excellent, thanks for doing that!

As an alternative, I was going to suggest the OP could read the output of git log main to find the most recent commit from before the bad push, reset main hard to that, and push with force. But I think your formulation is more elegant and probably easier too!
