# How do I create my own Git branch to work on?

Tags: git, github

My goal - to branch of from our development branch to be able to work on it separately. I was quickly shown how to do this as:

1. Open git shell or powershell/cmd and navigate to the folder where the project resides.
2. Run "git branch (desiredNameForMyBranch)". From what I understand this just creates a local branch.
3. Run "git checkout (desiredNameForMyBranch) - this switches to the branch locally?
4. Run "git push origin" - this creates the branch remotely?

Is this correct? (We are using github, but it's all the same git, right?). And yes, I realize I need to take a course on this on pluralsight or something, I just don't have four hours today to do it.

This is similar to what I need, here for reference if other people have the same q later: https://github.com/Kunena/Kunena-Forum/wiki/Create-a-new-branch-with-git-and-manage-branches

Comment: Yes, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide/816614#816614 and http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

Comment: Thank you, I will come back and upvote the answers once I meet the minimum rep requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do steps 2 (`git branch`) and 3 (`git checkout`) at the same time with `git checkout -b branchname`

For step 4, I am accustomed to `git push -u origin branchname` to explicitly create the branch remotely and set it as the upstream for your working branch. This lets you do `git pull` later without arguments to update your working copy from the remote branch. See [How do I push a new local branch to a remote Git repository and track it too?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765421/push-a-new-local-branch-to-a-remote-git-repo-and-track-it-too)

However, you can skip step 4 if you are only doing some short-term local development, depending on your group's chosen workflow. Local-only branches are commonplace + disposable (not replicated).

Comment: I really needed the branchname part of "git push -u branchname," that wasn't in my notes - thank you. What does the "-u" do? We are switching to pull requests, so I will need to push it.

Comment: The `-u` sets the remote branch (in this case, `origin branchname`) to be the "upstream" for your local branch. This means that future 'git pull' or 'git push' for your local branch will be able to infer the upstream branch.