# Git Branching and Merging

Tags: git

Being new to Git, how to handle the following scenario:

I'm working on a bug fix and I want to do that in a separate branch. I have a remote Git repo and I have cloned it. So when I do a git branch on my local file system, I can see that I'm pointing to the master. I then created a new branch using:

```
git checkout -b myBranchName
```

Is this newly created branch available in the remote repo?
Should I push it explicitly?
What is the best workflow for this?

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/q/2765421/1425848

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this newly created branch available in the remote repo?

Nope, the branch is a "private" branch which means that its a local branch until you push it to remote.

> Should I push it explicitly?

yes.

> What is the best workflow for this?

Im recommending on using [gitflow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).

Comment: [GitHub Flow](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/index.html) is also a very good choice for lightweight projects or just projects with a different release model than that expected by Gitflow.