# Branch exists locally, but not in the origin

Tags: git

When I enter a folder on my server, and type `git branch` command, I see the following result:

```
*develop
something_else
master
```

But when I enter my repository on bitbucket, I see that branch develop is not there. There's dev branch instead. Same thing in sourcetree.

What's wrong?

Comment: Have you ever pushed your develop branch to the origin? Have you pulled the dev branch from the origin?

Comment: Reading the following link will probably be a little hard for you, but it will make your life easier: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics

Answer (score 8):

You need to push to the remote:

```
git push -u origin <your branch name>
```

should do it.

More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765421/push-a-new-local-branch-to-a-remote-git-repo-and-track-it-too)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe branch develop is created by you in your local repo.

It is not yet pushed into your origin.

Comment: do the git push then you can see your repo in bitbucket