# Can i push a new local branch to remote 'feature/new_branch'?

Tags: git

Based on : [How do I push a new local branch to a remote Git repository and track it too?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765421/push-a-new-local-branch-to-a-remote-git-repository-and-track-it-too)

I have a local branch named as 'new_branch' and I would like to push the local branch to remote as the following:

```
$ git ls-remote origin
433ecee11614bcda452ddf5817ebb56212d96192        HEAD
94d6b198dd6bbba9520e8aa11a1d6fc67aed818a        refs/heads/feature/f1
76d6b198dd6bbba9520e8aa11a1dafc67aed818a        refs/heads/feature/f2

$git push -u origin feature/new_branch
```

The git reports the following errors:

fatal: 'origin/feature/new_branch' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

I try the following and it works for me but this is not what I want.

```
$git push -u origin new_branch
```

My local environment has not installed 'git flow'. Is it possible that I can directly push a non-feature local branch to a feature branch in remote?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to push it to feature/new_branch, do `git push origin new_branch:feature/new_branch -u`.

However, I would recommend that you just rename your local branch with `git branch -m new_branch feature/new_branch` first, then push it to origin, to avoid confusion later.