# How to create development branch from master on GitHub

Tags: git, github

I created a repo on GitHub and only have a `master` branch so far. My local working copy is completely up to date with the remote/origin `master` on GitHub.

I now want to create a `development` branch on GitHub so that other people on my team can start pushing changes to `development` (instead of directly to `master`) and submit PRs, request code reviews, etc.

So I tried creating a new `development` branch locally and pushing it:

```
git checkout -b development
git push origin development:master
```

But git just says `Everything up-to-date`. So I ask:

**If I'm current with `master`, how do I just create a remote `development` branch that contains an exact copy of `master`?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to push a new local branch to a remote Git repository and track it too?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765421/how-to-push-a-new-local-branch-to-a-remote-git-repository-and-track-it-too)

Answer (score 93, accepted):

When you do

```
$ git push origin development:master
```

What's actually happening is git is taking `<local>:<remote>` and updating `<remote>` to whatever the `<local>` branch is.

Since you executed `git checkout -b development` from `master`, your local `development` has all the commits `master` does; hence it shows as everything is up to date.

You can just do

```
$ git checkout -b development
$ git push origin development
```

to push the new branch

Comment: Is `develop` branch same with the other branches? I mean, is there any configuration that we need to setup for the `develop` branch? Just a bit confused

Comment: @Jonjie not that I know of. Any branch is the same in Git versioning - master could just easily be called 'main' or a feature-branch could just easily be used as 'master'.

Answer (score 146):

### Creating a git develop branch

You can list all of your current branches like this:

```
git branch -a
```

This shows all of the local and remote branches. Assuming you only have a single `master` branch, you'd see the following:

```
* master
  remotes/origin/master
```

The `*` means the current branch.

To create a new branch named develop, use the following command:

```
git checkout -b develop
```

The `-b` flag creates the branch. Listing the branches now should show:

```
* develop
  master
  remotes/origin/master
```

### Changing branches

You shouldn't commit anything directly to the `master` branch. Instead do all your work on the `develop` branch and then merge develop into `master` whenever you have a new public release.

You are already in your develop branch, but if you weren't, the way to switch is as follows:

```
git checkout develop
```

That's the same way you create a branch but without the `-b`.

### Making changes on develop

When making changes, add and commit as usual:

```
git add .
git commit -m "whatever"
```

The first time you push to your remote do it like so:

```
git push -u origin develop
```

The `-u` flag stands for `--set-upstream`. After the first time you only need to do it like this:

```
git push
```

### Merging develop to master

Once your `develop` is ready to merge into `master` you can do it like so:

First switch to your local master branch:

```
git checkout master
```

To merge develop into master do the following:

```
git merge develop
```

Then push the changes in local master to the remote master:

```
git push
```

Done.

### Deleting a branch

If you don't need the `develop` branch anymore, or you just want to delete it and start over, you can do the following:

Delete the remote develop branch:

```
git push -d origin develop
```

Then delete the local branch:

```
git branch -d develop
```

The `-d` means delete.

Comment: While accepted answer addresses is probably perfect for question, this one should be the accepted one

Answer (score 10):

You can also use git flow. This will automatically create the branch with the right naming convention, it's good practice.

```
git flow init
```

and to push

```
git push --set-upstream origin develop
```

Answer (score 6):

This works for me

```
git push origin development
```