# How do i git push specific branch?

Tags: git

I have two branch :

```
:git branch
  dev1.1
*  master
```

I have some local changes to the master I want to push. How do I specifically push master branch only?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to push a new local branch to a remote Git repository and track it too?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765421/how-to-push-a-new-local-branch-to-a-remote-git-repository-and-track-it-too)

Answer (score 10):

You can use the following:

`git push <remote_alias> <branch_name>`

So in your case, it would probably be:

`git push origin master`

Comment: wouldn't this push the currently checked out branch to origin/master?

Answer (score 4):

If you have already committed your change, then you can push your changes to remote from any branch.

```
git push origin branch_name
```

In your case, branch is `master`.

Answer (score 1):

you could use something like this:

```
git push git@github.com:bliep/blup.git fork-feature:feature
```

This will push your local `fork-feature` branch to the `feature` branch of the `git@github.com:bliep/blup.git` repository! I use this to help out colleagues with their PR's sometimes.

Answer (score -2):

If the history of your branch has changed and it is pointing to a different tip of the head, you'll need to do a force push as follows:

```
git push origin master - - force
```