# Push local branch to remote

Tags: git

I have created local branch:

```
git checkout -b tmp1
```

Now I would like to push this branch to server:

```
git push remote_tmp1 tmp1
```

Got error:

```
fatal: 'remote_tmp1' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How to push my branch to server?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765421/how-to-push-a-new-local-branch-to-a-remote-git-repository-and-track-it-too

Comment: you should only use your remote repository name: `git push remote tmp1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting that specific error because you have not added  `remote_tmp1` as a remote repository.

Add the remote repository first and then retry pushing:

`git remote add remote_tmp1 https://remoteserver.com/repository.git
git push --set-upstream remote_tmp1 tmp1`

You can add the remote using https as above or with ssh if available. For example if you're using Github you can use either: `https://github.com/username/repository.git` or `git@github.com/username/repository.git`.

Answer (score 0):

The git push syntax is:

```
git push <remote-name> <branch-name>
```

Therefore, replace your `<remote-name>` with the name of your remote (probably origin if you cloned from it).

If you don't know its name, just like them using `git remote`

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple:

```
git push origin tmp1
```