# Pushing a new branch in GIT

Tags: git

I am using GIT, and I have created a new branch (named `foo`) on my local (one that doesn't exist on the repository). Now, I have made some changes to my original project (master) files and committed all those changes in this new branch. What I would now like to do is push this new branch to the remote repository. How can I do that? If I just run `git push` while I am on the branch `foo`, will this push the entire branch to the repo. I don't want my changes to be pushed to master. I just want to push this new branch to the main repository.

Comment: I don't see any accepted answer in your 10 questions: please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer and http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I push a new local branch to a remote Git repository and track it too?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765421/how-do-i-push-a-new-local-branch-to-a-remote-git-repository-and-track-it-too)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. It'll prompt you to set the `upstream`.

Example

```
git branch --set-upstream origin yourbranch
```

It's same for everything except for the branch name.
Follow the on screen guidelines.

Comment: `--set-upstream` has been deprecated (and will soon be removed) in favor of `--track` or `--set-upstream-to`

Answer (score 10):

To push a branch onto a remote repository you should use this syntax

```
git push (remote) (branch)
```

Usually the first remote (and often the unique) is named "origin", thus in your case you would run

```
git push origin foo
```

It is usually advisable to run a slightly more complex command

```
git branch --set-upstream-to origin/foo
```

because "--set-upstream-to" (abbreviated "-u") sets a tracking on that branch and will allow you to push future changes simply running

```
git push origin
```

> "Tracking branches are local branches that have a direct relationship to a remote branch. If you’re on a tracking branch and type git pull, Git automatically knows which server to fetch from and branch to merge into." (cit. [git documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches))

Answer (score 3):

checkout in to your local branch and use: `git push -u origin <branch>`.
this will create the new branch at the remote and push all the changes

Answer (score 1):

`git push origin foo` should do the trick. Latest git versions only push single branches (so `git push` would work as long as you checked out `foo` ) unless you change push behaviour in git config.

Reference can be found [here](http://blog.santosvelasco.com/2012/07/15/make-git-push-the-current-branch-by-default/)

Answer (score 1):

If the upstream is defined OK, run the following command:

```
git push origin foo:foo
```

Comment: With commands like this, the whole `foo` `bar` syntax can be a bit too vague with annotating `foo(local)` `bar(remote)`. According to your example, the name has to be identical, which is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

use `git remote -v` to show your remote repo name and url:

```
origin   ssh://**/*.git (fetch)
origin   ssh://**/*.git (push)
```

origin is your remote repo name at local:
You can use this command to push your new branch to origin remote repo:

```
git push origin [your-branch-name]
```

Like this:

```
git push origin foo
```