# How to push new local branch to a branch of its own in git

Tags: git, github, version-control

I just created a branch in my local dev, (my remote only has one branch: master)

So, I created a branch in local using `git branch -b dev` which created the branch and made the switch.

Now I am used to only doing `git push -u origin master` but in this case, since I want to push a new branch to new branch, how do I do it without replacing master

Comment: I'm guessing you meant `git checkout -b dev` above, because `git branch` doesn't switch to a newly created branch and doesn't have a `-b` option anyway :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765421/how-do-i-push-a-new-local-branch-to-a-remote-git-repository-and-track-it-too