# fail to push new branch to remote repo on github (using -u flag)

Tags: git, github

I simple cloned a project using github copy & paste repository url, created new branch:

```
git checkout -b <branch>
```

added and commit changes, then pushed with -u flag:

```
git push -u origin <branch>
```

[exactly how describe here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765421/how-do-i-push-a-new-local-branch-to-a-remote-git-repository-and-track-it-too)

and I get:

> remote: Repository not found. fatal: repository
>   'https://github.com/companyUsername/MyRepo.git/' not found

never happened before...so weird :/

Answer (score 0):

### Problem: Wrong origin

> remote: Repository not found. fatal: repository 'https://github.com/MyRepo.git/' not found

Check your URL as it's in the form `https://github.com/username/repository.git`. You omitted your username. You can remove and re-add your origin like this:

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin "https://github.com/username/repository.git"
```

Comment: edited my question, in the actual action i didnt omitted it

Comment: Is it a private repository? Have you tried to copy the displayed clone URL when you setup the repository?

Comment: it is private repository. yeah i did copy it and in my console went `git clone https://github.com/CompanyUser/RepoName.git`

Comment: I imagine GitHub throws you an 404 error because you don't have sufficient permissions. Have you checked your user is added properly as an Contributor in the Repository settings page?

Comment: but if i checkout to master and go `git pull` i get a response...dosent it mean I have access?

Comment: As I don't use GitHub using private repositories I'm unsure whether you're able to set read/write permissions maybe? What messages do you get?