# How to upload my new branch to github

Tags: git, github

I have followed the following steps :

1. git pull
2. git checkout -b newBranch
3. Made changes

Now I want to push this to github but on a new branch "newBranch". How do I do it ?

Comment: git push origin newBranch should do the trick

Comment: create an answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I push a new local branch to a remote Git repository and track it too?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765421/how-do-i-push-a-new-local-branch-to-a-remote-git-repository-and-track-it-too)

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to commit your changes:

```
git status
git add -- <files>
git commit -m "Commit message"
```

You then have to `git push`:

```
git push -u origin newBranch
```

`-u` will set the upstream for your new branch so that you can do `git push`, `git pull` etc in the future without having to say where to / from.

Comment: fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository fatal: Could not read from remote repository. I get the above error

Answer (score 0):

`git push origin newBranch` will do the trick. Any time you need to push code, it's `git push [name of remote repository] [name of branch]`. in this case, the name of your remote is origin, and your branch is newBranch

Comment: fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.                                                                                        I get the above error

Comment: do you have a remote repository set up? run `git remote -v` and that should show you your remote(s). where are you pulling this from?