# Git - Branch I have different on bitbucket.org and when I looking from CMD

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

I want to look my latest commit on bitbucket. But when I look at the branches page, it different between when I look on CMD. Why? Help me please :)
[image]

[image]

Comment: I've already refresh my page, but it still same condition. (Btw, sorry if my english is bad)

Comment: this branch Fix_helper-class, you have only locally, not published yet

Comment: how can I publish it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765421/how-do-i-push-a-new-local-branch-to-a-remote-git-repository-and-track-it-too

Comment: okee, thanks alex :) @Alexan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the difference between remote branches in bitbucket and your local repo (check by cmd):

The branch `Fix_helper-class` does not exist in remote repo (bitbucket), and the remote branch `docs` does not exist in local repo.

- The reason why `Fix_helper-class` branch does not exist in bitbucket repo, that’s because `Fix_helper-class` branch is only a local branch and it hasn’t pushed to your bitbucket repo (as Alexan mentioned). And you can push the `Fix_helper-class` branch to your bitbucket repo by:

  ```
  git push -u origin Fix_helper-class
  ```
- The reason why `docs` branch does not show in your local repo, that because you haven’t checkout the remote docs branch locally yet, and you can checkout it to local repo by:

  ```
  git checkout docs
  ```

Besides, you can use the command `git branch -a` to check both local branches and remote branches. And use the command `git branch -vv` to check the tracking branches for your local repo.