# Git pushing to a branch for the first time

Tags: git

I am new to git and want to push all the files in a branch in git for the first time.There are no changes sitting on that branch currently.

My commands are like below

1. `git add` .
2. `git commit -m 'First time commit to staging'`
3. `git push origin Staging`

And I got the below error --

```
error: src refspec Staging does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://****@bitbucket.org/***/***.git'
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Read [ask] and try searching before asking a question. Show how you obtained this repo, what branch you're on, what changed you committed and so on.

Comment: Make sure youre curruent on `Staging` branch. Type this `git branch -v`..

Comment: Type `git status`, and then include the output from that command directly in your question.

Comment: Ah. use `git add -A` and check beforehands with `git status` you actually put files to staging.

Comment: @TruongDang I am on master branch currently. I tried with `git checkout Staging` which gives me an error `error: pathspec 'Staging' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

Comment: what does "git status" say ?

Comment: please seek help in github help pages, https://github.com/git-guides/

Comment: See responses at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765421/how-do-i-push-a-new-local-branch-to-a-remote-git-repository-and-track-it-too

Answer (score 4):

Only for the first time. Note that "your_branch_name" part you need to replace. Rest is same (most likely!).

```
git push --set-upstream origin your_branch_name
```

Answer (score 2):

Use below command if you first time pushing your repo to remote -

```
git pull --rebase
git push
```

The full syntax is:

```
git pull --rebase origin master
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new branch just use the command:

`git checkout -b [branchname]`

If you want to push the code then use:

`git push origin [branchname]`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are working by default on master (you didn't say you created a branch)
so you should push like this

```
git push origin master:Staging
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.
Assuming that you want to send your changes to origin master branch

`git push`

Answer (score 0):

If the remote branch doesn't exist yet you can use

```
git push -u origin HEAD
```