# I made changes to a local file in a Branch and did a commit but didn't push to the origin. How can I get the original file back?

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

Here's what I have:

```
MacBook:Ja.git alan$ git status
On branch alan-1
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/alan-1' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Is there anything I can do on the command line or with the Visual Studio options that will allow me to get back to the last time I pushed to the origin branch so the file I changed before I did the commit would be restored to the way it was?

[image]

Comment: It may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765421/how-do-i-push-a-new-local-branch-to-a-remote-git-repository-and-track-it-too?rq=1

Comment: use git reset --soft HEAD~1

Comment: OR you can check commit hash by git log and then do git reset <commit_Hash>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I undo the most recent commits in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-i-undo-the-most-recent-commits-in-git)

Comment: `git reset --hard origin/alan-1`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+undo+commit