# how could I recover deleted forked branch for pull request

Tags: git, github-pages, pull-request

I created a new pull request on github, and I happened to deleted the forked branch in my github account. Now the reviewers ask me modify something in the code, but I find my pr is isolated and I cannot modify it directly.

I got to find [this](https://help.github.com/en/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally#modifying-an-inactive-pull-request-locally) document, but I do not know what the step of `$ git fetch origin pull/ID/head:BRANCHNAME` mean.

Suppose my pr ID is `#708` and the repository that I submit my pr into is `https://github.com/facebookresearch/maskrcnn-benchmark` and I would like to have my pr merged into the master branch.

I tried to use `git fetch origin pull/#708/https://github.com/facebookresearch/maskrcnn-benchmark:master`, but it failed.

How could I continue to commit my pr please?

by the way, if I have a pr under-reviewing, how could I submit another pr without deleting the existing fork?

Answer (score 0):

Italics are crucial in the document you found. Everything *not* in italics is literal, which includes `head`. The ID only refers to the **digits** (no `#`, the included screenshot is a little unlucky):

```
$ git fetch origin pull/708/head:foobar
```

will do the job, with `foobar` being your new local branch name for the pull request.

Comment: Thanks, I have pulled the pr in my  local machine. by running `git remote -vv` I find the remote origin is the  official repository. If I have modified my code, could I submit the modification to the  pr with `git commit -m 'ddd'; git push origin local_branch` ?

Comment: What do you mean by *"the remote origin is the official repository"*? Well, I haven't tried it, but I guess you can just push to a new branch. Probably you want to push as [upstream (`-u`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6232535/1281339).

Comment: Hi, I am submitting the pr via forking the original repository and then click the button of `pull request`. I used to submit my modifications to my forked the repository and the modifications will be updated to the pr page. Now after training the method in the documents, I have downloaded the deleted forked repository to my local machine. But I cannot direct use `git push` because the downloaded repo is pointing at the original branch rather than the deleted forked pr repo. How could I further submitting the pr after I downloaded the repo please?

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but I guess you can just [change your remote (origin)](https://help.github.com/en/articles/changing-a-remotes-url) to your forked repository, push to that forked repository and then pull request again.