# Create a sub branch in Git from another branch

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-push

I have two branches: main and develop/selenium.

We on the test team want to work on develop/selenium so we would like to create new branches from it. Now I understand how to do that with git checkout -b "branch-name" develop/selenium.

The part where I get confused is when it comes to pushing this commit, for example when I write a test and go to commit it, I would do
git commit -m "something"

But then would I do (to push the local feature branch I'm working on to remote develop/selenium)
git push origin branch-name

And then to (push remote develop/selenium to remote main)

Is that how it would work or have I misunderstood?

In work we have been asked to clone develop/selenium and create branches on it, but I didn't think we could clone just the branch, would the main not just be cloned and we would still have to checkout develop/selenium and work from there right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I push a new local branch to a remote Git repository and track it too?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765421/how-do-i-push-a-new-local-branch-to-a-remote-git-repository-and-track-it-too)

Comment: no Joe, the question is if I create a sub branch off develop/selenium where does it need to be pushed

Comment: There is no such thing as a "sub-branch". Branch names have no parent/child relationship to other branch names. The only things that really matter are the commits themselves, which *do* have parent/child relationships to other commits. Moreover, branch names in *your* Git repository need not correspond to branch names in some *other* Git repository. The things that matter—in both repositories—are still just the *commits themselves*. The other Git repository will use its own branch names to help it find commits.

Answer (score 1):

According to what you have described you should do the following:
In case there are no multiple people working on `develop_selenium`, when you wish to commit and push your local changes to the remote `develop_selenium` branch you will have to do the following:
When inside the local `develop_selenium` branch

```
git add *
```

to add the changed files to be committed.
Then you should

```
git commit -am "what we have done here comment"
```

to commit the local changes.
And then

```
git push origin develop_selenium
```

to push it into remote `develop_selenium` branch.
Now you should switch to `master` branch on your local repository using

```
git checkout master
```

Now you should update local `master` with remote `master` using

```
git pull origin master
```

Now, when you still in your local `master` branch, you should merge local `develop_selenium` into local `master` using

```
git merge develop_selenium
```

This may give you conflicts which need to be resolved and changes committed before moving further.
Once merge of `develop_selenium` to master on local is committed, push local `master` to remote `master` using

```
git push origin master
```