# Error: src refspec refs/heads/main does not match any - error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/xxxxxx/xxxxx.git'

Tags: git, github

I'm fairly new to coding, and was creating a discord bot in javascript. I wanted to push it to github so I could host it with heroku, and I believe I linked them all etc, but when I type "git push" I get this error exactly- (well the x is for censoring)
error: src refspec refs/heads/main does not match any
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/xxxxx/Discord-Bot.git'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I push a new local branch to a remote Git repository and track it too?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765421/how-do-i-push-a-new-local-branch-to-a-remote-git-repository-and-track-it-too)

Comment: Looks like your repo on Github doesn't have a `main` branch (does it have `master`)? If you're pushing your first branch, you want `git push -u origin main`

Comment: Thanks so much for the suggestions, but I'm still getting the same error. I'll go back over it all, step by step but its probably just something I'm doing wrong.

Comment: What's the output from running `git branch` and from running `git log`? Have you made any commits yet?