# How to do a pull request when using a virtual env?

Tags: django, pycharm, virtualenv

This might be a silly questions but I am relatively new to programming.

I am working on a project- I cloned the project and I am now using a virtual env in Pycharm CE.

Once I am done making my code changes, how do I upload it to the main branch and submit a pull request since it is on a virtual env?

Do I check out the branch I created in the virtual env? I am completely lost on how to upload my changes to the git after I am done.

I ultimately want to make changes in the virtual env and then upload it to the bitbucket repo to request a PR

Comment: Are you changing the virtual environment?  Or are you just changing your script, which is not part of the virtual environment?

Comment: I am just changing the script

Comment: Then you just create your new branch (`git checkout -b my-big-change`), do `git add` for your file, `git commit`, and push it with `git push -u origin my-big-change`.  Then you can create a pull request for your branch.  The virtual environment is irrelevant.  That's just how you RUN your script.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I push a new local branch to a remote Git repository and track it too?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765421/how-do-i-push-a-new-local-branch-to-a-remote-git-repository-and-track-it-too)

Comment: yes it does thank you very much for clarifying! I thought the virtual environment would somehow interfere with my branch.