# I've changed my branching system. How can I sort it out on github?

Tags: git, github, branch, remote-branch

So I've kind of done something a bit unusual. I had a couple of branches, `master` and `dev`. `master` had the latest stable version, and `dev` would have the bleeding edge, and would be merged into `master` at release.

However, this isn't so good, as a lot of people when they make pull requests, will make it to the master branch. Recently, I had to close a pull request, and ask them to checkout a new branch from the dev branch, and make the changes there, as the dev branch was very far ahead of the master branch, and merging would have been very tricky.

So, I decided to make `dev` `master`, and make `master` `stable`.

The first thing I did, with `dev` checked out:

```
git branch -m master stable
```

Then switch to the new branch:

```
git checkout stable
```

Then move `dev` to `master`:

```
git branch -m dev master
```

So, locally I now had two branches, `master` (previously `dev`) and `stable` (previously `master`).

I then checked out each branch individually, and ran `git push origin <branchname>` for each.

### Problems

The first problem I noticed, was that even after the push, on the new `stable` branch (was master), I get this upon `git status`:

```
# On branch stable
# Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 6 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

git still thinks that remotely this branch is associated with `master`, and because I made `dev` into `master`, it thinks that `stable` is behind. How can I get git to associate this branch with the correct remote one?

The second problem I noticed, on GitHub, branch `dev` still exists. How can I remove the remote version?

The third problem, on GitHub, if I select branch `master`, below it says latest commit to the `dev` branch. Will that change with a few commits? Same goes for the other branch (it says latest commit to `master` for `stable`).

How can I get the remote fully up-to-date with what is in my local repo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) For your first problem, you need set up your branch `stable` to track a remote branch `origin/stable`

```
 git branch --set-upstream stable origin/stable
 git branch --set-upstream master origin/master
```

2) For your second problem,
delete remote branch using this git command

```
git push origin :dev
```

3) For your third problem, this will be alright after a commit, pull and push.

Comment: @Alex you are welcome. One more thing, instead of using `git push origin <branchname>`, you can configure git to always push the current branch to upstream. It would save sometime for you. For detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/820178/git-push-only-to-a-remote-branch/10829461#10829461