# Changing the Git remote 'push to' default

Tags: git, git-push, git-remote

I want to change the Git default remote branch destination so I could just

```
git push
```

Instead of:

```
git push upstream
```

Currently this is set to the origin remote and I want to set it to a different remote.

I tried to remove the original (cloned from) remote

```
git remote rm origin
```

Which did remove the original remote. But doesn't solve the `git push` problem. I still get:

> fatal: No configured push destination. Either specify the URL from the
>   command-line or configure a remote repository using...

I also tried to play with:

```
git remote set-url --push myfork origin
```

and other options but none seem to work (maybe because I deleted the origin remote too soon?)

Following the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820178/git-push-only-to-a-remote-branch) I tried to change:

```
git config push.default upstream (or matching)
```

but neither worked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Different default remote (tracking branch) for git pull and git push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916845/different-default-remote-tracking-branch-for-git-pull-and-git-push)

Comment: @BuZZ-dEE you realize you just tried to point me to an answer for a question I've asked 6 years ago right?

Comment: yes, but my comment is the default message, when you flag a question as a duplicate. I did it, because I think this question should be closed as a duplicate of the question linked in my comment.

Comment: The question was asked 3 years before your question.

Comment: Lol, true that, but again, this behavior is between extreme nitpicking to plain abusive, closing a 7 year old question, and doesn't help the community a bit

Comment: I think it does help the community.If someone searches for this topic, the related questions are linked.

Comment: Has this been answered?
Because I still can't get it to permanently set the default remote branch for master (for git push --all) , because "push -u"  doesn't:
 git push -u "origin" "master:RELEASE12345"  # Does not set it up permanently
If there is something to manually edit in .git/config I'm confortable with that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Another technique I just found for solving this (even if I deleted origin first, what appears to be a mistake) is manipulating git config directly:

```
git config remote.origin.url url-to-my-other-remote
```

Comment: This is not a good solution, git users should be able to pull/push from multiple repositories - although this will allow you to change the original's remote, it does not mean that you SHOULD change the original's remote, since this will likely mean that there are a number of incompatibilities between remotes. Merge will help here, but it is both simpler and preserves more history to set the remote on the new branch.

Comment: Not the proper way of doing it... @Jordan's answer is more apropriate

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2432799/1820106 (`git remote set-url origin PATH_TO_REMOTE`)

Answer (score 355):

You can use `git push -u <remote_name> <local_branch_name>` to set the default upstream. See the [documentation for git push](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-push.html) for more details.

Comment: Doesn't work: I get '''fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly''' maybe because I deleted origin remote before moving on. just found  a working solution, I'll update in an answer

Comment: As an additional clarification, the syntax should be `git push -u <remote_name> <local_branch_name>:<corresponding_remote_branch_name>`.

Comment: Example: `git push -u origin master:master`.

Comment: After setting a default remote...isn't there anyway that you can force `git push` to push remote branch of the current local branch? I mean doing it this means I have to run this command for every branch. Right? Can't I just do an initial setup for the entire repo? @MarcoLazzeri

Comment: How big is the branch problem? Assuming it's just for this repo, and you have Gnu Tools available: cat .git/config | grep -A 1 -e "^\\[branch"

Comment: That command shows all the branches in the repo and what remote they default to.

Comment: @starbeamrainbowlabs Isn't `git push -u origin master` sufficient? Are you just illustrating the full syntax?

Comment: @JosiahYoder Indeed, just an illustration of the above comment.

Comment: Note that it does not only set up the default upstream but also makes the push.

Comment: What about `git push -u origin head`? Why not use that? https://stackoverflow.com/a/66663502/470749

Answer (score 178):

To change which upstream remote is "wired" to your branch, use the `git branch` command with the upstream configuration flag.

Ensure the remote exists first:

`git remote -vv`

Set the preferred remote for the current (checked out) branch:

`git branch --set-upstream-to <remote-name>/<branch-name>`

Validate the branch is setup with the correct upstream remote:

`git branch -vv`

Comment: Just tried ```git branch --set-upstream-to myfork``` and got an error:
>error: unknown option `set-upstream-to' 
I'm running git 1.7.9

Comment: The syntax changed in 1.8, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch

Comment: See the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2432799/1820106 (`git remote set-url origin PATH_TO_REMOTE`)

Comment: `git branch -u <remotename>/<branch>` worked for me. The command was run with the local branch of interest checked out. See 'Tracking Branches' in https://git-scm.com/book/it/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer because it doesn't actually do a push (i.e., no unintended side-effects).

Comment: The remote command verbose output is really just `git remote -v` or `git remote --verbose`. The `-vv`'s extra v is redundant.

Comment: Instead of `git branch -vv` use `git branch -vv --list <local_branch_name>` to show only the specific branch (`<local_branch_name>`)

Comment: Make sure that you have previously fetched the remote repository!

Comment: It's actually `git branch --set-upstream-to <remote-name>/<branch-name>`.

Answer (score 93):

Working with Git 2.3.2 ...

```
git branch --set-upstream-to myfork/master
```

Now `status`, `push` and `pull` are pointed to `myfork` remote

Comment: This works when you just want to set the default for `pull`as well.

Comment: That is a perfect and concise answer.

Comment: This only work for push in certain cases, generally with matching names.  See [`push.default`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt-pushdefault)

Answer (score 59):

You can easily change default remote for branches all at once simply using this command

```
git push -u <remote_name> --all
```

Comment: Just to note, this will push them all, as well as changing their upstream remote.

Answer (score 27):

If you did `git push origin -u localBranchName:remoteBranchName` and on sequentially `git push` commands, you get errors that then origin doesn't exist, then follow these steps:

1. `git remote -v`

Check if there is any remote that I don't care.
Delete them with `git remote remove 'name'`

2. `git config --edit`

Look for possible signs of a old/non-existent remote. 
Look for `pushdefault`:

```
[remote]
  pushdefault = oldremote
```

Update `oldremote` value and save.

`git push` should work now.

Comment: Thanks! I tend to add `-u` when using `git push` to a different remote due to muscle memory. This makes the given remote the default, setting it back using `git config --edit` (or pushing again and setting a new remote) solved the problem.

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful since usually I change the name of the origin to something that is more descriptive.  Honestly I think this is the better answer since it seems like the person asking the question is trying to re-define origin/default remote repo.

Comment: This is the only answer IMO that solves the problem permanently and should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 24):

It might be helpful to take a look at `.git/config` inside your repo, it will list all remotes and also the default remote for each branch

eg.

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@gitea.xxx.be:fii/web2016.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "bugfix/#8302"]
    remote = origin
    merge = "refs/heads/bugfix/#8302"
[branch "feature/#8331"]
    remote = origin
    merge = "refs/heads/feature/#8331"
[remote "scm"]
    url = https://scm.xxx.be/git/web2016bs.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/scm/*
```

you can make manual changes in this file to remove an unwanted remote, or update the default remotes for the different branches you have

- Pay attention! when changing or removing the remotes make sure to update all references to it in this config file

Answer (score 15):

Just a clarification (using git version 1.7.9.5 on ubuntu 12.04):

Git will add/remove remotes. These are remote instances of git with a server attached.

```
git remote add myremote git://remoteurl
```

You can then fetch said git repository like so:

```
git fetch myremote
```

It seems this creates a branch named 'myremote', however the remote for the branch is not automatically set. To do this, you must do the following:

First, verify that you have this problem, i.e.

```
git config -l | grep myremote
```

You should see something like:

```
remote.myremote.url=git://remoteurl
remote.myremote.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/myremote/*
branch.myremote.remote=.
branch.myremote.merge=refs/heads/master
```

If you see `branch.myremote.remote=.` , then you should proceed:

```
git config branch.myremote.remote myremote
git checkout myremote
git pull
```

You should now be up to date with the remote repository, and your pulls/pushes should be tied to the appropriate remote. You can switch remotes in this manner, **per branch**. [Note][1]

According to [a The Official Git Config Documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config), you can set up a *default* push branch (just search remote.pushdefault on that page), however keep in mind that this will not affect repositories/branches which already exist, so this will work but only for new repositories/branches. You should remember that `--global` will set user-specific repository defaults (~/.gitconfig), `--system` will set system-wide repository defaults (/etc/gitconfig), and no flag will set configuration options for the current repository (./.gitconfig).

Also it should be noted that the **push.default** config option is for configuring *ref-spec* behavior, **not** *remote* behavior.

[1]: `git branch --set-upstream myotherremote` would usually work here, however git will complain that it will not set a branch as its own remote if `git branch --set-upstream myremote` is used. I believe however that this is incorrect behavior.

Comment: Instead of `git config -l | grep myremote`, you can simply use: `git config --get branch.myremote.remote`

Comment: @Murmel first, this is a community wiki so feel free to improve, second, `--get` assumes particular behavior, I make a note that there are other ways to set upstreams but this provides a way to find the information without only relying on git tooling to be correct. Git isn't perfect, its better to understand the data, what it does and then hope its invocations work appropriately.

Answer (score 10):

In my case, I fixed by the following:
* run `git config --edit`
* In the git config file:

```
[branch "master"]
remote = origin # <--- change the default origin here
```

Answer (score 9):

In the [git man pages](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-remotepushDefault), you'll find the following:

> `remote.pushDefault`
> The remote to push to by default. Overrides `branch.<name>.remote` for all branches, and is overridden by `branch.<name>.pushRemote` for specific branches.

Answer (score 8):

Very simply, and cobbling together some of the great comments here along with my own research into this.

First, check out the local branch you want to tie to your remote branch:

```
git checkout mybranch
```

Next:

```
git branch -u origin/mybranch
```

where:

```
git branch -u {remote name}/{branch name}
```

You should get a message:

```
"Branch mybranch set up to track remote branch mybranch from origin."
```

Answer (score 3):

### `git push -u origin head` is what I was looking for.

---

Here is what it solves for me:

```
fatal: The current branch task/PLAT-1924-datagrid-tool-panel-scrollbar has no upstream branch.
To push the current branch and set the remote as upstream, use

    git push --set-upstream origin task/PLAT-1924-datagrid-tool-panel-scrollbar

➜  frontend git:(task/PLAT-1924-datagrid-tool-panel-scrollbar) git push -u origin head
```

Instead of using my mouse to go up and copy the suggestion from Git (`git push --set-upstream origin task/PLAT-1924-datagrid-tool-panel-scrollbar`) and then paste that and run it, I can use a keyboard shortcut or alias to type `git push -u origin head`, and it doesn't need to be branch-specific.

UPDATE: Oddly, today I got [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4181861/470749). Changing lowercase `head` to uppercase in the above command solved the problem, though.

<sub>Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/23402125/470749.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

`git remote set-url --push origin` should work, as you mentioned, but you need to explicitly provide the url instead of an alternative remote name, e.g.

```
git remote set-url --push origin git@github.com:contributor/repo.git
```

You can confirm whether this worked by doing a `git remote -v`. E.g.

```
λ ~/go/src/github.com/stretchr/testify/ master git remote -v
fork    git@github.com:contributor/testify.git (fetch)
fork    git@github.com:contributor/testify.git (push)
origin  git@github.com:stretchr/testify (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:contributor/testify.git (push)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#_description) say:

> When the command line does not specify where to push with the `<repository>` argument, `branch.*.remote` configuration for the current branch is consulted to determine where to push. If the configuration is missing, it defaults to **origin**.