# github how to remove push destination

Tags: git-push

This is a problem occurred in a GitHub corporate site.
I had a repository in my account folder (unnnn/CCS_src1).  Then I moved it to a group folder(app-FST/CCS_src1).  Then I cloned it to my laptop. Everything went fine until I ran "git remote -v"

```
$ git remote -v
    origin  https://github.xxxx.com/app-FST/CCS_src1 (fetch)
    origin  https://github.xxxx.com/app-FST/CCS_src1 (push)
    origin  https://github.xxxx.com/unnnn/CCS_src1 (push)
```

There are two push destinations.  How do I remove the destination https://github.xxxx.com/unnnn/CCS_src1?

Many thanks to your answer in advance.

Andrew K

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove remote origin from Git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16330404/how-to-remove-remote-origin-from-git-repo)

Comment: @9301293 I tried "git remote remove origin".  It threw an error: Could not remove config section 'remote.origin'

Comment: Edit your git config file manually.

Answer (score 2):

I think in your case the simplest thing might be

```
git remote remove origin && git remote add  origin  https://github.xxxx.com/app-FST/CCS_src1
```

This will require you to set an upstream branch, again; You should get some warning.

[This response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18801147/changing-the-git-remote-push-to-default) would also help, if both remotes weren't labeled to push as 'origin'.

Comment: It is working.  Apparently, I ran the commands more than 1 time and created some unexpected errors.  But when I ran "git remote -v".  It only showed one push destination.