# Set default push target

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

How can I set the default target for a push in Visual Studio Code? I currently have two targets configured (github and azure) and want to set the "Push" action from the menu to one of the two.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the Git remote 'push to' default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18801147/changing-the-git-remote-push-to-default)

Answer (score 3):

I'd try to set the default remote in your project's configuration. Perhaps, VSC uses it to know where to push?

You can do it as follow:

```
git config remote.pushDefault nameOfYourRemote
```

And from `man git-config`:

> ```
> remote.pushDefault
>        The remote to push to by default. Overrides branch.<name>.remote for all branches, and is overridden by branch.<name>.pushRemote for specific
>        branches.
> ```

And the section about `branch.<name>.remote` (that `remote.pushDefault` overrides):

> ```
>    branch.<name>.remote
>        When on branch <name>, it tells git fetch and git push which remote to fetch from/push to. The remote to push to may be overridden with
>        remote.pushDefault (for all branches). The remote to push to, for the current branch, may be further overridden by branch.<name>.pushRemote. If
>        no remote is configured, or if you are not on any branch, it defaults to origin for fetching and remote.pushDefault for pushing. Additionally,
>        .  (a period) is the current local repository (a dot-repository), see branch.<name>.merge's final note below.
> ```

Which allows you to have `origin` still, but also other remotes and one of them being the default one instead of `origin`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure within VSC but from the command line. `git push -u <remoteName> <branchName>`. Remote would either be GitHub or azure.

Comment: Got it, but the main thing is really how to tell VSC which target should be my default remote target.