# How to change default remote repository?

Tags: git, git-remote

I have 2 remove repositories (`origin1` and `origin2` for example).

And `origin1` is my default remote repo.
How can I change my default remote repo, so when i do `git push` commits push to `origin2`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing the Git remote 'push to' default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18801147/changing-the-git-remote-push-to-default)

Comment: This element of config happens at branch level, not remote.

Comment: In the `.git/config` file every branch has `remote = ` line. Change that.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the remote repository your local branch is currently tracking

```sh
git branch local_branch_name --set-upstream-to origin2/remote_branch_name
```

or

```
git branch local_branch_name -u origin2/remote_branch_name
```

After this, your `pull` and `push` will be done on the new tracked remote.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried "git remote add" command?
https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/using-git/adding-a-remote