# Create branch -> Push it to new repo -> Make changes -> Pull and merge with original branch and push it there

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I'm afraid, that while trying to do (subj) on the one of last steps I'll face the blocker.

Right now I work with group who has limitation to 5 people on their BitBucket account. I want to create branch and push it to another account (BitBucket or other) invite 2 more people to make some job on this 2ns account. When work done, I want to pull 2nd repo merge 1st repo and push it there.

Is it possible, and what is the best way to do so if it's not possible in the way described?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, it is possible.

In your local clone (with a remote '`origin`' referencing your original BitBucket repo which is maxed out with 5 people), add a new remote (here named '`second`') to an empty BitBucket repo:

```
git remote add second https://bitbucket.org/<user>/<secondrepo>
```

Then push [your one branch to that second repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/820217/6309):

```
git push second <yourBranch>
```

At any time, you can make a `git fetch second`, see how second/ has evolved, and merge it to one of your original branches.