# Is there way to store a fragment of my repository for deployment and be able to git pull

Tags: git, file, deployment, pythonanywhere

I have a repository that directory stucture looks like below

```
-- Frontend
  -- Frontend files
-- Backend
  -- Backend files
```

The
I am now looking to deploy the backend to Pythonanywhere. Pythonanywhere works as remote cloud console for deployment. I want to be able to store just the backend content without the frontend to save on memory. Do I have to break the repository into frontend and backend repos, or this there a .gitfocus command or function to only pay attention to changes in the backend folder.

Comment: If you just want to _deploy_ certain files/folders from a Git repo, what would be stopping you from writing a bash script which does just this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in "[Git push deployments on PythonAnywhere](https://blog.pythonanywhere.com/87/)", if you want to git push your files in order to trigger a deployment, you will need to have indeed two repositories.

Even if you had two branches (one per folder), and [pushed only one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/820217/6309), those branches have (with your current repo) too much common history, and you would end up pushing the full history anyway.

Having separate repositories (grouped locally in a parent repo through [submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)) is cleaner.